# HoloLens works as UDP server but not as client

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, hololens

I try to send data from my PC (server) to my HoloLens (client) in UWP apps.
My primary goal is to use "Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket" for the HoloLens receiver because else the code does not work in unity. 
I already accomplished the system with **wrong roles**. The HoloLens sends data to the PC but with "System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient" instead of DatagramSocket...
Here you can see the important code parts:

```
// Current client application on PC (using System.Net.Sockets...)
HostName serverIp = new HostName("192.168.0.109");
string port = "1337";

async void Client()
{
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(); //creating socket
    socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived; //attach receive event
    await socket.BindEndpointAsync(serverIp, port); //bind socket
}

async void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender,
DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args) //receive event
{
    Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
    string msg = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    Print("Message received: " + msg); 
}


// Current Server application on HoloLens (using Windows.Networking.Sockets...)
IPAddress serverIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.109"); 
const int port = 1337;

async void Server()
{
    var udpClient = new UdpClient();
    var serverEP = new IPEndPoint(serverIp, port);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello from Client!"); //parse
    await udpClient.SendAsync(bytes, bytes.Length, serverEP); //send
}
```

The PC succesfully receives the message from the HoloLens.
**My problem:** When I swap server and client application on the devices that the PC sends (with UdpClient) and the HoloLens receives (with DatagramSocket), the message is not received anymore.
Both devices have connection to the network, I disabled firewall at the PC and in both appxmanifests "PrivateNetworks" is enabled.

Does anybody can figure the reasons?

Kind Regards

Comment: A server should not use an IP address to listen.  You should use IPAny so you can port code to any PC.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow made it work but I unfortunately can't tell the difference.
My problem now is that the communication only works in one direction. I can write to the socket and the message arrives but I can't send messages from the socket back.

When I want to write from a socket I must not use "socket.BindEndpointAsync()" but "socket.ConnectAsync()" right? But no matter if I use a DataWriter or the OutputStream attribute no message can be received by my actually working receiver.

```
        writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        writer.WriteString("test");

        IBuffer buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test").AsBuffer();
        await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
```

Maybe somebody can help me.

Kind regards